# LLVM printing IR calls

Tags: llvm

I am following LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial, 3rd chapter and it seems that additional information is being printed out on compiled code when an operation is run.

```
ready> 4+5;
Read top-level expression:
define double @0() {
entry:
  ret double 9.000000e+00
}
```

But when I compile everything myself, i only get:

```
ready> 4+5;
ready> Parsed a top-level expr
```

I the code can be found on https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html, I compile it the same way as in the tutorial.

```
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config-11 --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```

It seems that in example from the tutorial it prints `Read top-level expression:` but I get `Parsed top-level expression:`. I am very new to LLVM so apologies for a trivial question.

Comment: Just guessing here… the lines that aren't printed looks generally like things LLVM prints if the library itself is compiled with debugging options enabled. (I haven't actually reconfigured my own LLVM tree in a while and have forgotten exactly how I did it. But compiling with assertions enabled is at least advisable, and if you see other debugging-related options, enabled those too for good measure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting a `Parsed a top-level expr` is because you most likely changed that string yourself.

If you visit the body for `HandleTopLevelExpression`, you see where the tutorial prints this message.

https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html#full-code-listing

---

The printing of LLVM IR to stderr is done with various `llvm::Value::print`, called on the line below the one where it writes `Read top-level expression`.

To conclude, your code is missing parts from the code listing in the tutorial